Understanding definition of degree of a holomorphic function at a point p
I am confused at the following notation:
Let $f$ be non constant meromorphic function in a domain $U$
and $D$ a open set whose closure is a compact subset of $U$.
Let $q\in \hat{\mathbb{C}}$, we set
$$N_f(D,q)= \sum_{p\in f ^{-1}(q)\cap D}\deg(f,p)$$
Where $\deg(f,p)=$ord$(f-f(p),p)$. And ord$(f,p)$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that the coefficient of the power series of the function $f$ in a disc centered at $p$ is non-zero.
The set $f^{-1}(q)\cap D$ is finite and possibly empty by identity theorem, hence the sum is well defined.
In other words $N_f(D,q)$ is the number of solutions of the equation $f(z)=q$ in $D$, counting multiplicities.
I do not see how that notation counts the solution to that equation.
Let $p$ be a solution of that equation $f(z)=q$ then $f(z)-q=f(z)-f(p)$ for all $z$. Then I suppose I must somehow ord$(f-f(p),p)\geq 1$, since its count it? But if I let $f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n(z-p)^n$ be the power series representation. Then I have
$$f(z)-q=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n(z-p)^n-q=\sum^\infty_{n=1}a_n(z-p)^n$$
since $f(p)=q\implies a_0=q$. This tells me $f-f(p)$ has no constant term. I guess this means order must be geq 1. But I dont see how this counts the zeroes.... I must not see some simple fundamental thing here, could someone help me point it out? Thanks!

In the expression $$N_f(D,q)= \sum_{p\in f ^{-1}(q)\cap D}\deg(f,p),$$
$p\in f^{-1}(q) \cap D$ gives $f(p) = q$ and $p\in D$, i.e., $p$ is a solution of $f(z) = q$. It remains to count multiplicities, i.e., we would like to show $\deg(f,p) = \operatorname{ord}(f-f(p),p)$ is the multiplicity of the zero of $f - q$ at $z = p$.
This follows by definition. Let $p\in f^{-1}(q) \cap D$, i.e., $p$ is a zero of ${g}(z) = f(z) - q$. Say the multiplicity of this zero is $M\geqslant 1$. Then, $$f(z) - q = f(z) - f(p) = (z-p)^M\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-p)^n = \sum_{n=M}^\infty a_{n-M} (z-p)^{n},$$
near $p$, where $a_0 \ne 0$. Indeed, $M$ is also the smallest integer such that the $M^{\text{th}}$ coefficient of the power series is non-zero. So, by the definition of $\operatorname{ord}$, we get $M = \operatorname{ord}(f-f(p),p)$. The other direction is very similar.
